# Height of a div to be equal to another

Tags: css, html, inline

I have a simple page. [image]

HTML and CSS are as follows.

```
<body>
    <div style="background-color:red;">
        <div style="background-color:green; width:40%; float:left;">
            LEFT
        </div>
        <div style="background-color:blue; width:60%; float:right;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.
        </div>      
    </div>

</body>
```

The problem is that the contents of blue div come from php and it causes variable height of blue div. What I want, is to have the height of the left green div to be same as the height of blue div.
I've solved this one using jquery but can I achieve this one only with html and css?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't float the elements, wrap the elements using a wrapper `div`, assign `display: table;` to the wrapper element, and than assign `display: table-cell;` to nested elements, that's all you need to achieve what you want to..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8YFvP/)

```
.wrap {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrap div.one, div.two {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
}

.wrap .one {
    background: #f00;
}

.wrap .two {
    background: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: That's good but using table/ table properties are considered bad practice... can we do without using table properties?

Comment: @AaronH: Where do you see tables for layout here? Because I don't.

Comment: as far as flexbox support goes, yours is yet the best solution. you've got upvoted from me.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on which browsers you need to support, you could use [CSS flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/).

Simple example:

```
div{
    display: flex;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/heCwJ/)**

- [CSS Flexbox browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

Comment: Thanks Brian Frisch. That does it. :)

Comment: You're welcome. But be sure that CSS flexbox is supported in the browsers you need to support.

Comment: Would the down voter care to elaborate on the reason for the down vote? Not that I'm offended at all - merely curious.

Comment: @BrianFrisch, dont even bother. Asking reasons for downvote's is pretty much useless here. be happy that the OP found your answer useful and marked as answer. +1 from me

Comment: @MarsOne Alright. Thanks for the heads up :-) ! I was just wondering. Thanks.

Comment: @BrianFrisch I was downvoted too but for a foolish reason, as MarsOne told you, don't ask, few care to reply.. +1 though ;)